# How to retrieve the EKS kubeconfig?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have defined an **aws_eks_cluster** and **aws_eks_node_group** as follows:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "example" {
  count = var.create_eks_cluster ? 1 : 0
  name     = local.cluster_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.example[count.index].arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [
      aws_subnet.main2.id, 
      aws_subnet.main3.id
    ]
    security_group_ids = [
      module.network.security_group_allow_all_from_client_ip,
      module.network.security_group_main_id
    ]
    endpoint_private_access = true
    endpoint_public_access = false
  }

  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Cluster handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EKS managed EC2 infrastructure such as Security Groups.
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEKSVPCResourceController,
  ]
}


resource "aws_eks_node_group" "example" {
  count = var.create_eks_cluster ? 1 : 0
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.example[count.index].name
  node_group_name = random_uuid.deployment_uuid.result
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks-node-group-example[count.index].arn
  subnet_ids      = [
    aws_subnet.main2.id, 
    aws_subnet.main3.id
    ]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 5
    min_size     = 1
  }

  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Node Group handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EC2 Instances and Elastic Network Interfaces.
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.example-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the KubeConfig?

I have seen that the kubeconfig is available as an output on the **eks module**.

Do I need to replace **aws_eks_cluster** and **aws_eks_node_group** with the **eks module**?

Answer (score 1):

The EKS module composes a kubeconfig based on [a template](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v13.2.1/templates/kubeconfig.tpl).

You can include that template alongside your terraform code.

You will need to provide default values for all the variables in the [templatefile function call](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v13.2.1/local.tf#L139) and reference your own EKS resource name. It's fine to drop all the `coalescelist` functions too.

e.g.:

```
locals {
  kubeconfig = templatefile("templates/kubeconfig.tpl", {
    kubeconfig_name                   = local.kubeconfig_name
    endpoint                          = aws_eks_cluster.example.endpoint
    cluster_auth_base64               = aws_eks_cluster.example.certificate_authority[0].data
    aws_authenticator_command         = "aws-iam-authenticator"
    aws_authenticator_command_args    = ["token", "-i", aws_eks_cluster.example.name]
    aws_authenticator_additional_args = []
    aws_authenticator_env_variables   = {}
  })
}

output "kubeconfig" { value = local.kubeconfig }
```

Comment: Just for anyone else who comes here, like I did, `terraform-aws-module` [removed support](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/681e00aafea093be72ec06ada3825a23a181b1c5/docs/UPGRADE-18.0.md#variable-and-output-changes) for printing out the kube config. The recommended way is via the aws cli - `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name>` (as the doc above states.)